# How to split a multi-delimited string using regex for creating hive table?

Tags: regex, split

I'm trying to create hive table with multi-delimiter (I can't use multi delimiter serde in hive as we need to update the jar file),for example I want to split the following string with a *two-character* delimiter `#$`:

```
1234#$CSI#$MAN # NO#$MANN#$1212#$N
```

The desired result is:

```
1234 | CSI | MAN # NO | MANN |1212 | N
```

When I have tried `#$` the result is

```
1234 | CSI | MAN | NO | MANN |1212 | N
```

**How could I split the string with a two-character delimiter `#$`?**

Comment: There's no need to use a regular expression. Just split it using the literal string `#$` as the delimiter.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of what `[]` means in regular expressions? Every day I see a new regexp user who thinks it's for grouping. I don't understand why this happens so much. `[#$]` matches either `#` or `$`, it doesn't match them as a sequence. That's what `(#$)` is for.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Just escape `$`, `#\$`, see https://regex101.com/r/rz3tVG/1

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have also tried (#$) but this didn't work, what worked with me is using the escape ```#\$```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(.*?)#\$(.*?)#\$(.*?)#\$(.*?)#\$(.*?)#\$(.*)`

See: https://regex101.com/r/0KYFYi/1/

But as @Barmar said, splitting via `#$` would be way easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want: `(.+?)(?:#\$|$)`

[Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B%5E%5C%24%5D%2B%29%28%3F%3A%23%5C%24%7C%24%29&i=1234%23%24CSI%23%24MAN%20%23%20NO%23%24MANN%23%241212%23%24N&o=m)